# Implementation of factory method pattern with dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, solid-principles, factory-method

I am trying to better understand the use of the factory method pattern and adhering to SOLID principles and I am not sure if my implementation is correct for the following reasons:

1. The dependencies my `IBankAccountAddOnService` implementations need (instantiated in my factory) the larger my `BankAccountAddOnFactory` constructor is going to get. Shouldn't each `IBankAccountAddOnService` be responsible for its own dependencies via DI?
2. In the constructor params for each `IBankAccountAddOnService` implementation not only do they contain their dependencies but also the concrete type of `IBankAccountAddOn` specific to that service (e.g. `CreditCardAddOn` for `CreditCardAddOnService`). This feels wrong and is why I can't use DI to set them for each service. How could I get the `BuildAddOn` method to take in the relevant concrete `IBankAccountAddOn` instead?
3. Does the `switch` statement violate the `Open Closed Principle` or is it ok within a factory?  If there were many more bank addons in future, the switch statement may become very large?

**`IBankAccountAddOn` and it's implementations (there may be many of these)**

```
public interface IBankAccountAddOn
{
    int Id { get; }
}

public class CreditCardAddOn : IBankAccountAddOn
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public double Limit { get; set; }
    public double BalanceTransfer { get; set; }
}

public class TravelInsuranceAddOn : IBankAccountAddOn
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public int? MonthsDuration { get; set; }
}
```

**IBankAccountAddOnService that my factory creates dependent upon `IBankAccountAddOn`**
**Note** - The `IExternal...` interfaces are from 3rd party libraries.

```
public interface IBankAccountAddOnResult
{
    bool Success { get; set; }
    List<string> Errors { get; set; }
}

public class BankAccountAddOnResult : IBankAccountAddOnResult
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public List<string> Errors { get; set; }
}

public interface IBankAccountAddOnService
{
    IBankAccountAddOnResult BuildAddOn();
}

public class CreditCardAddOnService : IBankAccountAddOnService
{
    private readonly IExternalCreditCardService _creditCardService;
    private readonly IRepository _repository;
    private readonly CreditCardAddOn _creditCardAddOn;

    public CreditCardAddOnService(IExternalCreditCardService creditCardService, IRepository repository, CreditCardAddOn creditCardAddOn)
    {
        _creditCardService = creditCardService;
        _repository = repository;
        _creditCardAddOn = creditCardAddOn;
    }

    public IBankAccountAddOnResult BuildAddOn()
    {
        var customerDetails = _repository.GetCustomer(_creditCardAddOn.CustomerId);

        if (!customerDetails.CanApplyCreditCards)
        {
            return new BankAccountAddOnResult
            {
                Success = false,
                Errors = new List<string>{
                    "Customer cannot apply for credit cards"
                }
            };
        }

        var result = _creditCardService.Apply(_creditCardAddOn);
        return result;
    }
}

public class TravelInsuranceAddOnService : IBankAccountAddOnService
{
    private readonly IExternalTravelInsuranceService _travelInsuranceService;
    private readonly TravelInsuranceAddOn _travelInsuranceAddOn;

    public TravelInsuranceAddOnService(IExternalTravelInsuranceService travelInsuranceService, TravelInsuranceAddOn travelInsurance)
    {
        _travelInsuranceService = travelInsuranceService;
        _travelInsuranceAddOn = travelInsurance;
    }

    public IBankAccountAddOnResult BuildAddOn()
    {
        var result = _travelInsuranceService.Apply(_travelInsuranceAddOn.CustomerId, _travelInsuranceAddOn.MonthsDuration, _travelInsuranceAddOn.Start);
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Factory implementation**

```
public interface IBankAccountAddOnFactory
{
    IBankAccountAddOnService Create(IBankAccountAddOn addOn);
}

public class BankAccountAddOnFactory : IBankAccountAddOnFactory
{
    private readonly IExternalCreditCardService _creditCardService;
    private readonly IExternalTravelInsuranceService _travelInsuranceService;
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    public BankAccountAddOnFactory(
            IExternalCreditCardService creditCardService,
            IExternalTravelInsuranceService travelInsuranceService,
            IRepository repository
        )
    {
        _creditCardService = creditCardService;
        _travelInsuranceService = travelInsuranceService;
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public IBankAccountAddOnService Create(IBankAccountAddOn addOn)
    {
        switch (addOn)
        {
            case CreditCardAddOn creditCard:
                return new CreditCardAddOnService(_creditCardService, _repository, creditCard);
            case TravelInsuranceAddOn travelInsurance:
                return new TravelInsuranceAddOnService(_travelInsuranceService, travelInsurance);
            //Many other addon cases
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
}
```

**Service that creates add ons for customers**

```
public class BankAccountAddOnService
{
    private IBankAccountAddOnFactory _bankAddOnFactory;

    public BankAccountAddOnService(IBankAccountAddOnFactory bankAddOnFactory)
    {
        _bankAddOnFactory = bankAddOnFactory;
    }

    public IBankAccountAddOnResult Apply(IBankAccountAddOn addOn)
    {
        var applyService = _bankAddOnFactory.Create(addOn);
        var response = applyService.BuildAddOn();

        //Do something with response

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: In terms of design patterns, I suggest starting with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739611/what-are-the-differences-between-abstract-factory-and-factory-design-patterns. Note that this code is neither, i.e. it is not a GoF pattern at all. This code is sometimes called a Simple Factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The dependencies my IBankAccountAddOnService implementations need (instantiated in my factory) the larger my BankAccountAddOnFactory constructor is going to get. Shouldn't each IBankAccountAddOnService be responsible for its own dependencies via DI?

I don't understand "each [service] be responsible for its own dependencies via DI." The whole point of DI is that classes are *not* responsible for their own dependencies-- the code that instantiates the class is.

And yes it is normal to have a constructor with more and more arguments as dependencies are added. If you have trouble with this, see [Constructor injection: How many dependencies is too many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953407/constructor-injection-how-many-dependencies-is-too-many).

> In the constructor params for each IBankAccountAddOnService implementation not only do they contain their dependencies but also the concrete type of IBankAccountAddOn specific to that service (e.g. CreditCardAddOn for CreditCardAddOnService). This feels wrong and is why I can't use DI to set them for each service. How could I get the BuildAddOn method to take in the relevant concrete IBankAccountAddOn instead?

It's okay to inject a concrete type, obviously, but the class receiving the injection should not rely on it. Instead, define an interface for the things it relies on, and add that interface to the concrete type. It's OK if that interface contains all the concrete type's members.

Example:

```
public interface IBankAccountAddOnService
{
    IBankAccountAddOnResult BuildAddOn();
}

public interface ICreditCardAddOnService : IBankAccountAddOnService
{
    int CustomerId { get; }
}


public class CreditCardAddOnService : ICreditCardAddOnService
{
    public CreditCardAddOnService(IExternalCreditCardService creditCardService, IRepository repository, ICreditCardAddOn creditCardAddOn)
    {
        //etc
```

> Does the switch statement violate the Open Closed Principle or is it ok within a factory? If there were many more bank addons in future, the switch statement may become very large?

No, it does not violate OCP in and of itself.

If the list gets very large, you can implement as a map instead, e.g.

```
var map = new Dictionary<Type,Func<IBankAccountAddOnService>>
{
    { typeof(CreditCardAddOn), () => new CreditCardAddOnService(_creditCardService, _repository, creditCard) },
    { typeof(TravelInsuranceAddOn), () => new TravelInsuranceAddOnService(_travelInsuranceService, travelInsurance) }
}
```

With the map in place, you can do this:

```
public IBankAccountAddOnService Create(IBankAccountAddOn addOn)
{
    return map[addOn.GetType()]();
}
```